# UI automation and controls

Tags: c#, ui-automation

I am inheriting a project that has quite odd requirements. This is not a WPF project but a Winforms project which basically runs and when a user clicks on certain buttons, it launches a 3rd party tool and automates that using some external dll which I think has Win32 calls.

What I want to know is, since this application "launcher" needs to be automated itself from another application, how is it possible to find out what buttons exists on that form and be able to invoke it?

what about being able to use Win32 (or other means) to be able to "track" or "click" on elements which is not known to us but somehow we can get handles to say a menu item or a tab control or a specific tab on that control and be able to click it?

any thoughts on this?

essentially, I want to be able to get a list of known items we need to invoke and play around with then be able to perform some automation against those items/handles.

the app is developed in C# and .NET Framework 3.5 Winforms.

Comment: How about valuepatterns?

Comment: Thanks. Since I have no knowledge of such an area - can you explain more in depth with some helpful examples? Thank you

Comment: Please check System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement,its GetXXXPattern will return some info, besides, you could download 'UISpy' and have a try. I am newbie too...

Comment: Any other responses folks? not sure why the -1 however...

Answer (score 1):

instead of UISpy.exe use the Inspect.exe as suggested [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms727247%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#fbid=zcDwJOZm3kD) to read properties from your winForm application.

As Lei Yang suggested [UIAutomation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is your friend!

to find your application, here is an example code.

```
int processID; //look up at your applications processID with your windows taskexplorer under processes (PID)
Condition yourCondition = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ProcessIdProperty, processID);
AutomationElement mainWindow = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Element | TreeScope.Children, yourCondition);
```

A button can then be found nearly the same way.

```
String buttonId;//your Button ID
Condition yourCondition2 = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationId, buttonId);
AutomationElement yourButton = rootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Element | TreeScope.Descendants, yourCondition2);
```

an then invoke it with the [invokePattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.invokepattern.aspx)

But you should definitly read the documentation provided in the link above and google some basics about UIAutomation..